# Correct way to define elements with xsd:all

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to xml and I am trying to understand the xsd:all element. 
As MSDN says:

> xsd:all allows the elements in the group to appear (**or not appear**) in any order in the containing element.

So, as I understand if we make a simple example of xsd schema:

```
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" >  
    <xsd:element name = "MyElem">
     <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name = "name" type = "xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name = "lastname" type = "xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name = "city" type = "xsd:string" />
            </xsd:all>
     </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
```

then we can have an xml file like this:

```
<MyElem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Example.xsd" >
    <name>"some_name"</name>
    <lastname>"some_last_name"</lastname>
    <city>"somecity"</city>          
</MyElem>
```

This is pretty clear. But when I try to give to **MyElem** no elements, as there is mentioned in definition (allows elements appear or **not appear**), I get error in xml file, which says:

> following elements are expected at this location.

I am using Altova xmlSpy xml editor.

Does I understood correctly that elements may or may not appear in the containing element?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some elements to be optional, give them `minOccurs="0"`. To specify that name, lastname, and city may all occur in any order, with city being optional:

```
<xsd:all>
  <xsd:element name = "name" type = "xsd:string" />
  <xsd:element name = "lastname" type = "xsd:string" />
  <xsd:element name = "city" type = "xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xsd:all>
```